# Multibinding StringFormat for Class and Text

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I  have a StackPanel which looks like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{helpers:Localization PIV_HdrTblPtnId}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(utils:NavigationVariables.Id)}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I am trying to transform it to a single TextBlock as follows:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                    <Binding Path="{helpers:Localization PIV_HdrTblPtnId}"/>
                    <Binding Path="(utils:NavigationVariables.Id)"
                                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> 'A 'Localization' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of
>   type 'Binding'.

Is there a way I can solve this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Localization class:

```
public class LocalizationExtension : Binding
{
    #region Constructors

    public LocalizationExtension(string name) : base("[" + name + "]")
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        Source = CultureManager.Instance;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the question should be closed, its pretty easy to understand what I am asking without given a minimum running example.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You can't use a LocalizationExtension (or any other Binding) as the value of the Path property of another Binding. As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` on the other Binding is pointless. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, so I understand it cannot be done that way, but there is a way I can modify either `LocalizationExtension` or the binding to accomplished it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TextBlock with two Runs should work:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{helpers:Localization PIV_HdrTblPtnId}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=(utils:NavigationVariables.Id), Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, its working, I had to add to the second run `Mode: OneWay` because it was throwing another error. But with that is working as expected.

Comment: Right, the `Run.Text` property binds TwoWay by default.